# Quadratic Equation to prove $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Tags: contest-math, quadratics

"Prove that there is one and only quadratic equation for which the sum of the roots is $3$ and the cubed of the roots is $63$"

I'm practicing for the Maths Olympiad. I'm a high school student and it's too hard for me. Can you please solve it for me?

Comment: I hope you mean that "sum of cube of roots is 63"

Comment: What does "cubed of the roots" mean? Do you mean the sum of cubs of roots?

Comment: There is definitely more than one such equation. If $f(x)$ is one, then $2f(x)$ is a different one. I suspect you might want $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\alpha + \beta = 3 = -\frac{b}{a}$$
$$\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = 63 \Rightarrow (\alpha + \beta)^3 - 3\alpha\beta(\alpha + \beta) = 63 \Rightarrow \alpha\beta = -4 = \frac{c}{a}$$
$$b=-3a$$
and $$c=-4a$$
So the required unique equation is as follows:
$$x^2-3x-4=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b$ are the roots,

$$p+q=3$$

$$63=p^3+q^3=(p+q)^3-3pb(p+q)\implies pq=?$$

Comment: @Wojowu, Agreed